# Why does UdpClient even have SendAsync?

Tags: sockets, .net-core

The `UdpClient` class in `System.Net.Sockets` has a method `SendAsync` that causes me pause.

From what I know of UDP this function is never going to be asynchronous. How can Send be any more blocking than SendAsync when sending a UDP datagram?

Comment: It can never be asynchronous? Is there no case in which the OS would delay accepting a new packet with UDP? I imagine the OS has some kind of buffer and would pause accepting when that buffer is full.

Comment: The whole thing with UDP packets is that they are unbuffered. You give winsock the packet. It tries to send it. If it fails, it returns immediately. So I am wondering if (a) I misunderstood the non blocking nature of a UDP send all along, or if (b) .NET just blindly assumes any send "could" be blocking or if (c) .NET is actually being clever and catering for things like just-in-time name resolution. i.e. a UDP send to a hostname will trigger a DNS lookup that should be handled as async.

Comment: Certainly a good question. I am skeptical, though, that the OS would not create back pressure through blocking when it's own buffers are full. I'd be surprised if packets were just dropped then. UDP certainly is not defined to be unbuffered. Routers have (limited) buffers AFAIK.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this ?